# Get class object from a react component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to dynamically add markers to the here api map. I have an app that uses shodan and a geolocator to get the location of all ips connected to that IP. this is working fine.

My issue is updating a react component that is already loaded in react.

```
const map = <DisplayMapClass/>\\this is an atempt to save the object before it is called
  const asyncFunc = async () => {
      
      setLoading(true);
      const response = await fetch('http://68.71.131.14:5000/test/8.8.8.8'  );
      const data = await response.json();
      for(var x in data){
        addMarker(map, x["lat"], x["lng"])
      }
      setLoading(false)
  }
  
  \\if i can get the map object from the component i will be able to update the map
  const addMarker = (map, x, y) => {
    var marker =  new H.map.Marker({"lat": x, "lng": y})
    map.addObject(marker);
  }
```

Above is the code attempt to make the changes it. the variable is considered undefined.

tldr; i need away of retrieving an object from a component.

bellow is a link to the repository.

https://github.com/frostWorks96/MapMyStalkers/

Comment: wouldn't it be best to update state using react hooks? so your api would make a call and update the map markers in your components state. The component will auto-reload when it detects a change in state. https://blog.bitsrc.io/making-api-calls-with-react-hooks-748ebfc7de8c?gi=8b8963806c49

Comment: I'm a little uneducated when it comes to react. Even with hooks or the api, I still have the problem of not being able to get the Map object from the component. But thanks for the link im a little more educated on hooks

Comment: Looking at states I can see you can set your own state with props. Can you access a components props. Or is that only within the class

Comment: state is information internal to a component, props is information passed from a parent component down to a child component

Comment: @LeslieAlldridge ok so would the parent be app.js and the child is any component that is being rendered. if so how can you retrieve that information.

Comment: yea correct, app.js could render a component like <MyComponent name='hello'/> and then in your MyComponent.js you can use props.name to access the value 'hello'

Comment: Please do let us know if you are facing any issue related to HERE product and services.